# upgradation from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS in machine with GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Tags: unity, upgrade, graphics

My machine is running 12.04 LTS with nvidia graphic card support GeForce GTX 750 Ti. I need to upgrade to 14.04 LTS. However, the upgradation failed due to the error stating that the machine doesn't have 3d support for running unity desktop environment.
Please guide me to solve the problem.

Comment: Well I guess you need a higher spec card. Im not an Nvidia guru but the 750 is an old card isnt it ? Why not try something other than unity. Xfce (Xubuntu) is an excellent choice and has lower spec machines in mind. I have got a modern spec laptop and I still use Xfce. If you have your heart set on unity then I think you need a new card.

Comment: @hatterman The GTX 700 Series is pretty much previous generation. Not old at all. I guess OP is using an ancient driver. Are you using the proprietary NVIDIA drivers, or `nouveau`? Which version? Append that to your question.

Comment: Ahh, OK. I just saw 700 and thought 7000 ! I'm not a big user of Nvidia so not particularly up to speed. To be honest, I probably shouldn't have commented in hindsight.